# Laravel download xls file with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I can't download my XLS file via Ajax

```
function downloadFile(response) {
        var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'})
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        location.assign(url);
    }

    $('#export').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'factures/engagements/selected/export',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                checkboxes : checkboxValues
            }
        }).done(downloadFile);
    });
```

my controller :

```
public function exportFacturesEngagementSelected(Request $request){

    $checkboxes = $request->input('checkboxes');

    $collection = collect($checkboxes);

    $engagements = EngagementOrder::whereIn('id' , $collection)->get();

    $date = Carbon::now('Europe/Paris')->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');

    $output = Excel::create('factures_engagements' . $date. '', function($excel) use ($engagements) {
        $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($engagements) {
            $sheet->loadView('engagements.exportExcelSelected')->with("engagements", $engagements);
        });
    })->export('xls');

    return $output;
}
```

I only get the output preview of the file in my console network, but nothing happens in my browser; no file is downloaded. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE @matticustard solution :

my checkboxValues is a json for exemple the result is

> {920: "920", 927: "927", 931: "931", 939: "939"}

when i console log query i get :

> undefinedcheckboxes=920&checkboxes=927&checkboxes=931&checkboxes=939&

When i try to get the values to my controller i made a $request->all() and i get :

```
array:2 [
  "undefinedcheckboxes" => "920"
  "checkboxes" => "939"
]
```

why i get undefinedcheckboxes and why i don't get the other ids ?

Comment: pretty sure `createObjectURL` requires base64 encoded data to work correctly

Comment: thanks for the reply, how could i do that ?

Comment: *"how could i do that ? "* `return base64_encode($output);` well in Laravel you might need to use `return \base64_encode($output);` ?  To use the [global namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php)

Comment: On second  thought  i think it should be more or less like like ->   `return "data:application/octet-stream;base64," . base64_encode($output);`

Comment: `dataType: "json",` expects a json response.

Comment: true @RolandStarke still the `data:application/octet-stream;stream;base64, ..`  is missing or it needs to happing on the PHP side or the Javascript side somewhere as   `URL.createObjectURL(..)` can't work with raw data..

Comment: a [dataURItoBlob](https://gist.github.com/yashwant/2baef805c09e0f3b35d24fd682808f76) which converts a data url to a blob  seams also to be a missing link here..

Comment: i removed dataType: "json", and now i can download the file but the excel file is corrupted.

Comment: I dont get it, the only mistake i see is dataType, because `location.assign(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['example'], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'})))` works just fine.

Comment: so for dataType what should i use ?

Comment: Nothing or `"text"`. But you did that, so idk. (Personaly I would try switching to GET and open the url directly, or use a form, or set the response type to blob, and get rid of the `new Blob` line.)

Comment: i did that in the past but my problem is that i collect checkboxes from a pagination with refresh so i need to use AJAX to send the checkboxes from all the page .. that's why i choose AJAX method :/

Comment: i will try with get and open url

Answer (score 1):

Try this

if your ajax success

```
location.href = path/to/file/property_title.xls
```

change this line

```
->export($type);
```

with

```
->store($type, 'public/reports/', true);
```

Comment: i don't want to store the file. it's not possible ?

Comment: I think it`s not, you should delete the file after download @MathieuMourareau

Answer (score 0):

These days I've used [this package](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) 
 (my recommendation) for converting my model's collections to XLS and export that.
As I understand, you want to download the file via AJAX. I didn't got you at all, but I just can share my experience for helping you. This working with a normal POST request, but it will not refresh your page anyway.
So this is a working example:

1. In Controller

> ```
> public function export(Request $request)
> {
>     $data = $request->get('data'); // get incoming data field
>     return \Excel::download(new ExcelService($data), "custom-file-name-with-extension.xls");
> }
> ```

2. In Service (or you can implement this in controller too)

> ```
> namespace App\Services;
>
> use App\Models\Item;
> use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
>
> class ExcelService implements FromCollection
> {
>     protected $data = null;
>
>     public function __construct($data)
>     {
>         $this->data = $data;
>     }
>
>     public function collection()
>     {
>         $items = Item::where('data', $data)->get(); // some query using incoming $data
>         return $items;
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Route

> ```
>  Route::post('export', 'ItemController@export')->name('export');
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reason to use AJAX or store the file.  You can pass the checkbox data as parameters in the URL with a GET request and use an `<iframe>` to download the file.  I guessed at the controller name, so adjust as necessary.

**web.php**
Change the route to `GET`.

```php
Route::get('factures/engagements/selected/export', 'FactureController@exportFacturesEngagementSelected')->name('export');
```

**JavaScript function and handler**
Serialize the data as expected by your controller and make the request.

I guessed that `checkboxValues` was an array of values based on the actions taken in your controller.  But you could serialize the form directly `var query = $('form').serialize();` and adjust the controller to match the input.

```js
function downloadFile() {
    var query;

    $.each(checkboxValues, function(index,value) {
        query += 'checkboxes=' + value + '&';
    });

    $('<iframe />')
        .attr('src', '/factures/engagements/selected/export?' + query)
        .hide()
        .appendTo('body');
}

$('#export').click(function () {
    downloadFile();
});
```

**FactureController.php**
And use the download method in your controller.

```php
// ...
->download('xls');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, this solution will be the best i updated my post in order that you see my actual problem with your solution. I'm sure i'm close to the result. @matticustard